How to change MULTI-LINE-MODE and SINGLE-LINE-MODE?
It seems, that the both similar questions do not contain the information I seek.
I don't get how the mode change works in CL-PPCRE. I tried it with both, embedded modifiers as with the keyword arguments. Can you explain the behaviour to me?
EDIT: The question is answered. The major problem trivially was a wrong example string.
The source code below is the original request (with 2 EDITS):
;; From: https://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut
;;    "Here are the four possible combinations:
;;     $x = "There once was a girl\nWho programmed in Perl\n";
;;     $x =~ /^Who/;   # doesn't match, "Who" not at start of string
;;     $x =~ /^Who/s;  # doesn't match, "Who" not at start of string
;;     $x =~ /^Who/m;  # matches, "Who" at start of second line
;;     $x =~ /^Who/sm; # matches, "Who" at start of second line
;;     $x =~ /girl.Who/;   # doesn't match, "." doesn't match "\n"
;;     $x =~ /girl.Who/s;  # matches, "." matches "\n"
;;     $x =~ /girl.Who/m;  # doesn't match, "." doesn't match "\n"
;;     $x =~ /girl.Who/sm; # matches, "." matches "\n"

;; <<<<<<<<<EDIT: This was the main problem here:>>>>>>>>>>>
(defparameter *x* "There once was a lady\nWho programmed in Lisp.\n")

;; I was pointed out on #commonlisp that I had simply copied 
;; the Perl string: 
;; "There once was a girl\nWho programmed in Perl.\n".
;; I was so focussed on the regexp that I treated the TARGET string
;; the same. (So my first revision attempt actually was:
;; "Oh yes. You're right: 
;; 'There once was a lady\\nWho programmend in Lisp.\\n'." 
;; Goofy, me.)
;; So it should have been, of course:
;; -----------------------------------------------------
;; (defparameter *x* (str:concat "There once was a lady"
;;                               (string #\Newline)
;;                               "Who programmed in Lisp."
;;                               (string #\Newline)))
;; ------------------------------------------------------

;; <<<<EDIT: And this was the second (misplaced modifiers)>>>>>
;;     Once, a condition was signaled when I put one in the front. But
;;     apparently I was crossed-eyed in that moment ...
(ppcre:scan "^Who" *x*)         ; => NIL
(ppcre:scan "^(?s)Who" *x*)     ; => NIL
(ppcre:scan "^(?m)Who" *x*)     ; => NIL -> unfortunately ... differs from tutorial
(ppcre:scan "^(?sm)Who" *x*)    ; => NIL -> as well
(ppcre:scan "lady.Who" *x*)     ; => 17, 25, #(), #() -> as well
(ppcre:scan "(?s)lady.Who" *x*) ; => 17, 25, #(), #() -> as well
(ppcre:scan "(?m)lady.Who" *x*) ; => 17, 25, #(), #() -> as well
(ppcre:scan "^(?sm)Who" *x*)    ; => NIL -> as well

;; Maybe I embedded the modifiers at the wrong place?
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^Who")))
  (ppcre:scan s *x*)) ; => NIL
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^Who" :single-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s *x*)) ; => NIL
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^Who" :single-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s *x*)) ; => NIL -> nnnnope
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "lady.Who" :single-line-mode t
                                          :multi-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s *x*)) ; => 17, 25, #(), #() -> At least consistent
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "lady.Who" :single-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s *x*)) ; => 17, 25, #(), #() -> as well
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "lady.Who" :multi-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s *x*)) ; => 17, 25, #(), #() -> as well
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^Who" :single-line-mode t
                                      :multi-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s *x*)) ; => NIL -> as well

The entry in my problem of understanding was this:
;; So (three let forms just for three explicit outputs):
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode nil)))
  (ppcre:scan s "\\n"))                              ; => NIL -> like above
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode nil)))
  (ppcre:scan s "a"))                     ; => 0, 1, #(), #() -> like above
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode nil)))
  (ppcre:scan s "a\\n"))                             ; => NIL -> like above

;; This seems to be the default setting. Now, let's try the opposite:

(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s "\\n"))                              ; => NIL -> like above
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s "a"))                     ; => 0, 1, #(), #() -> like above
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s "a\\n"))                             ; => NIL -> like above

;; Oops.

;; The documentation:
;;   "* Consider using 'single-line mode' if it makes sense for your task.
;;      By default (following Perl's practice), a dot means to search for
;;      any character except line breaks. In single-line mode a dot searches
;;      for any character which in some cases means that large parts of
;;      the target can actually be skipped. This can be vastly more
;;      efficient for large targets."

;; So, by default :MULTI-LINE-MODE is T. But why there is no effect?

(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode nil :single-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s "\\n"))                              ; => NIL -> like above
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode nil :single-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s "a"))                     ; => 0, 1, #(), #() -> like above
(let ((s (ppcre:create-scanner "^.$" :multi-line-mode nil :single-line-mode t)))
  (ppcre:scan s "a\\n"))                             ; => NIL -> like above

I thank you very much for your hints.

I just tried out the quality of answering my question with chatgpt. I like the tool, but here it is not that helpful, because it seems to start with Adam and Eva. Anyway - I saw, that I do can place the embedded modifiers at the first position of the regexp. Before, a condition was signaled when I placed it there. Obviously there must have been another typo which I didn't recognize.
Anyway, even in first position there is no change.

The documentation claims that (?sm) should work. The keyword arguments are just for your convenience. You can always use embedded modifiers like "(?i-s)" instead.

You have a syntax error in your defparameter, by the way. Too many closing parens.

You have some problems with your regular expressions: "^(?m)Who" should be "(?m)^Who", for example. With that change,
CL-USER> (ppcre:scan "(?m)^Who" *x*)
22
25
#()
#()

The scanner has to be in multi-line mode before seeing the ^ so it knows to match at the start of a line, not just at the start of the string.
Some others:

"lady.Who" should fail to match as . doesn't match newline. Indeed:

CL-USER> (ppcre:scan "lady.Who" *x*) 
NIL

but you indicate in a comment in your code that it is matching. Are you sure *x* is what you think it is?

The next one,

CL-USER> (ppcre:scan "(?s)lady.Who" *x*)
17
25
#()
#()

you also say those results are unfortunate, but they're exactly what I would expect. Going into single-line mode makes . match a newline, after all.

and then

CL-USER> (ppcre:scan "(?m)lady.Who" *x*)
NIL

multi-line mode doesn't change what . matches so a failure here is expected; but again your comments suggest it matches for you?

Finally, "^(?sm)Who" again has the ^ too early to be affected by the mode changes:

CL-USER> (ppcre:scan "^(?sm)Who" *x*) 
NIL
CL-USER> (ppcre:scan "(?sm)^Who" *x*)
22
25
#()
#()


Thanks a lot. Apparently, the last evening I was lost in my attempts to find my mistakes and after I was pointed out on #commonlisp, that my *x* was wrong (the unbalanced parens in the code snipped above are just a typo here) - and after I realised that the modifiers can be embedded in the front, I checked the wrong cases and did not properly update my code snippet up there.
I'm sorry for that.
"unfortunate" only in the context, that the return values were different from those in the Perl tutorial.
But now it matches. And your comments to the single calls are very helpful.
